# PCD file in ROS?

Tags: ros, object-recognition, 3d-object-recognition, pcd, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have published Points2 type point cloud in ROS using Minoru camera.
Can we generate a PCD file in ROS of these published point clouds? How can we process this PCD file using ROS? Purpose is to create an input file for object detection and then recognition.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12813/pcd-file-in-ros?/) by [PriyankaP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1050/priyankap/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2012-01-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl/Overview) tutorial for conversion from ROS data types to PCL datatypes. You can then use PCL's built-in PCD input/output.

[This](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl_ros) tutorial might also contain some useful information.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3